# tag:lxc and tag:lxd ... clarification required

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[lxc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxc) and [lxd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxd) seem to be partially overlapping tags.

So while LXC is the acronym for LinuX Containers and names the project as well as the software, there are now three major versions of LXC: 1.x through 3.x.

The LXC >=2.x versions are often referred to as LXD (after the `lxd` daemon). However, `lxd` (the daemon) and `lxc` the LXD command line client are two different entities. Yet both belong into the category LXC 2.x.

In the old LXC 1.x version there was no program called `lxc`, instead all the tools were prefixed with `lxc-`, such as for example `lxc-create` and `lxc-ls`.

So I think we should either:

1. clarify what these tags stand for in particular (e.g. does [lxd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxd) refer to LXC >=2.x in general, *including* its `lxc` command line client?), or
2. migrate existing LXC 1.x questions to a [lxc-1.x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxc-1.x) which would have to be created (and possibly do something similar with a [lxc-2.x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxc-2.x)), or
3. some other means to clarify the intent when using either tag ([lxc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxc) and [lxd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxd)), i.e. your idea here ;)

For now, when I want to refer to "client-side" questions (i.e. using the `lxc` command line client) about LXD, I was using both [lxc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxc) and [lxd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxd). But I figure it makes more sense to reach some consensus within the community rather than making my own rules.

Comment: Based on very little experience on the topic and very little research on the questions here, and mainly on the small quantity of them, how reasonable would it be to have a single “Linux container” tag and merge the existing Q’s together?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: well the problem with that *might* be that people are confusing one with the other. It's conflating two related but still distinct topics, really.

Comment: As I understand it, LXC is the underlying technology and concepts, whereas LXD is an implementation of the toolset (Redhat docs point out the coincidentally named utility `lxc` that belongs in the LXD packages).

Comment: @Qix and exactly *that's* the issue. What does [tag:lxc] refer to? The client command line tool of LXD or the technology? Tags are always lowercase, so this is very ambiguous. Does it refer to the technology or the command line tool? To LCX 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @0xC0000022L `lxc` refers to the technology. The command line utility is not referred to as often in dialog or literature. `lcx` could definitely have some extra tags for `lxc-1.x` and `lxc-2.x` if necessary. But I see no reason these two are being conflated. LXD's `lxc` still deals with `lcx` so there's a good chance the `lxc` tag is relevant, too. I don't think a sweeping action is going to help a lot here IMO.

Comment: @Qix: agreed, it's not yet, because it's comparably new (especially if you use packaged software rather than building your own). My point is that quite literally and unless you're interested in the underlying technology - which would be better suited for StackOverflow than here - `lxc` now and the future is more likely to refer to the command line tool. Yet, because of `lxc-1.x` questions referring to the incompatible older tools will be tagged the same. Aren't tags there to help make easy distinctions rather than add to the confusion? Sweeping would be just one possible path ...

Comment: @Qix,  did you mean to type lcx in your comments above.  Is "lcx" supposed to mean LinuxContainerXYZ?

Comment: It was a typo @rjt. No need to be snarky.

Comment: @Qix, i am new to this.  Since it was a typo repeated by both of you,  i thought maybe it was referring to something  else.  Thanks for contributing.   No intentions of being snarky and generally try to avoid that attitude. Well until this evening on Twitter  when asked what improvements i would like to see in Google. Chrome, but i digress.

Comment: @rjt: `lcx` was the typo, yes. `lxc` is the proper acronym for LinuX Containers (hence LXC).

Comment: Just a tiny side note: whatever the (future) course of action, choosing a tag that overlaps with other container technologies (Docker, Virtuozzo/OpenVZ,.…) like "Linux container" should be avoided.

Comment: @benaryorg you should definitely be more specific. Docker started out with liblxc. It later acquired its own library "backend" and has taken ages to learn the trick of running an unprivileged container. LXC 1.x could do it! So the overlap with Docker would be marginal. Or do you mean the overlap of the term container in conjunction with Linux? Because, sorry to be the bearer of bad news, [but you're almost 12 years too late](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC). Perhaps, though, the project itself recognized this and has since preferred LCX over "Linux Containers" (original project name)?